# How to group LINQ to Entities results by enum and date?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Let me acknowledge up front that I'm probably not asking this question correctly because I realize you can't exactly use `GroupBy` on a `DateTime` value, but I've been working in Objective-C for four years and I haven't used LINQ much at all.  Here's my current code:

```
var filteredEvents = events.Where(e => e.EventDate < DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMonths(1)).GroupBy(e => e.EventStatusKey);
```

In this code, `events` is an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous type consisting of four fields, including the `EventDate` (`DateTime`) and `EventStatusKey` (`enum`).

Currently, the above code returns two groups for event status `Ready` and `InProgress`.  However, I need to break down `Ready` events based on the date as well.  Specifically, I need separate groups for `Ready` events where:

`EventDate >= DateTime.Date.Today`

and

`EventDate < DateTime.Date.Today`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do something like this:

```
var filteredEvents = 
    events.Where(e => e.EventDate < DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMonths(1))
    .GroupBy(e => new {
        e.EventStatusKey,
        BeforeToday = e.EventDate < DateTime.Today
    });
```

This will group for all statuses and whether or not it's before today. You can then collapse the groups (for example when it's InProgress) like so:

```
var inProgress = filteredEvents.Where(fe => fe.Key.EventStatusKey == InProgress)
                               .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Which will flatten the groups, essentially ignoring the 'BeforeToday' flag.

Comment: I had looked at using anonymous types (is that right?) for the GroupBy lambda but I didn't understand that each component was actually creating a new key.   Seems obvious in hind-site but I really appreciate your help with that.

Comment: @WilliamSmith Not a problem, happy to help. Yes, it is indeed creating an anonymous object. It works because now the anonymous object is now a key - and anonymous objects implement `.Equals()` and `.GetHashCode()` so that two distinct objects with the same properties are viewed as equal